# How can I pass a user input as a variable for a stored procedure C#, .NET 4.8, ASP.NET MVC, SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.8

I am quite new and wanted to build this project as a practice but I can't for the life of me figure this out. The project is build using C#, .NET framework, ASP.NET MVC and Microsoft SQL Server.

The project should be able to take a user input (an "OrderNumber") and pass it as a variable to a stored procedure. The procedure checks the DB for the row in the table with that order number. If it's not found it throws an error and if it finds it it checks another column called "ScanStatus". It is a bool that if it's 1 it gives the error "already scanned" and if it's 0 it updates to 1. I can't get this to work for the life of me but here's the code below. Any help would be appreciated immensely.

This is the controller

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Data;
using WebApplication1.Models;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class ScanController : Controller
    {
        private static void UpdateScanStatus(bool Scan_Status, string connectionString)
        {
            //Update the Scan_Status Column 
            string commandText = "UPDATE SpeedPassBd.Orders SET Scan_Status = @scan_status" + "WHERE Order_Number = @Onumber;";
            string xmlData = "<Orders><ID>''</ID><Order_Number>@Order_Number</Order_Number><Customer_Name>''</Customer_Name><Scan_Status>@scan_status<Scan_Status><QR_Number>''</QR_Number></Orders>";

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SBSQL;User ID=SpeedPass;Password=********;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;Trust Server Certificate=False;Application Intent=ReadWrite;Multi Subnet Failover=False"))
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
                command.Parameters.Add("@scan_status", SqlDbType.Bit);
                command.Parameters[@scan_status].Value = Scan_Status;

                //Use AddWithValue to assign OrderNumber
                //SQL server will implicitly convert strings to XML.
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Order_Number", xmlData);

                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    Int32 rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    Console.WriteLine("RowsAffected: {0}", rowsAffected);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

This is the model class:

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Web; 
  
namespace SpeedPass.Models 
{ 
     public class Orders 
     { 
         [Key] 
         public string Order_Number { get; set; } 
  
         [Required] 
         public string Customer_Number { get; set; } 
  
         [Required] 
         public bool Scan_Status { get; set; } 
     } 
}
```

This is the DbContext

```
using System; 
using SpeedPass.Models; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Data.Entity; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Web; 
 
namespace SpeedPass.Data 
{ 
     public class SpeedPassDbContext : DbContext 
     { 
         public SpeedPassDbContext() : base("Data Source=SBSQL\\SB_SANDBOX_DB;Initial Catalog=testDB;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;Trust Server Certificate=False;Application Intent=ReadWrite;Multi Subnet Failover=False") 
         { 
         } 

         public DbSet<Orders> Orders { get; set; } 
         public DbSet<Customers> Customers { get; set; } 
     } 
}
```

This is the stored procedure

```
Use [testDB]
GO

SET ANSI_NULL ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateScanStatus]
    @OrderNumber varchar(8)
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Orders WHERE Order_Number = @OrderNumber)
Begin
    DECLARE @ScanStatus BIT;
    SELECT @ScanStatus = ScanStatus
    FROM Orders
    WHERE Order_Number = @Order_Number

    IF @ScanStatus = 1
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Order is already scanned!', 23,1);
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Orders
        SET Scan_Status = 1
        WHERE Order_Number = @OrderNumber
        
        PRINT 'Successful!';
        END
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN

        RAISERROR('Order does not exist!'22,1);
    END
END;
```

I would like to give more info here though being new I don't know what to explore. I've looks a Microsoft documentation, C# corner and some other sites using different versions of frameworks as well as using scaffolding tools. Pretty much up to this point trial and error. The stored procedure works on the DB finding and updating columns as well as error handling.

Comment: while debugging, are you able to get `Ordr_Number` at the breakpoint?

Comment: What stored procedure are you referring to? I see the call to `db.Orders.FirstOrDefault` but that's not actually calling a stored procedure; it's just accessing the `DbSet`. If you're actually intending on calling a stored procedure, I don't think that's happening here.

Comment: @naveen I don't even know how I would debug this. Do you know any resources to teach how to debug? Also give me some time and I'll get the stored procedure for you. It is called "UpdateScanStatus". Sorry I left that out

Comment: Added procedure to question @naveen

Comment: That stored procedure isn't very useful. You already loaded the Order, just check its status and modify it if needed. The entire stored procedure can be replaced by a *single* `UPDATE ... WHERE OrderNumber=@order AND Status!=1`. There's no reason to search for the order twice, or throw an error if a matching record isn't found.

Comment: As for calling a stored procedure, that's done using ADO.NET, not ORMs or frameworks. Additional libraries can make it easier, eg [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper) can reduce the code to a single line and even open/close the connection for you

Comment: EF Core 7 allows executing non-query SQL as easily as Dapper, as [the docs show](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries#executing-non-querying-sql). `context.Database.ExecuteSql($"EXEC myProc {order}");`. This particular syntax isn't using string interpolation - `ExecuteSql` will call the stored procedure and pass the `order` variable as a parameter

Comment: Hey there and thanks for the patience. I've updated the controller to try get this running. Heres the updated controller and does anyone know how to see what the program is doing when I try to run the procedure?